# How to show all departments where in March 2014 there were sales of goods with a price of less than 400

Tags: sql, oracle

Please find below Tables.
How to show all departments where in March 2014 there were sales of goods with a price of less than 400?

```
  CREATE TABLE dep
    (
       id     NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
       city   VARCHAR2 (100) NOT NULL,
       name   VARCHAR2 (100) NOT NULL,
       CONSTRAINT dep_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );
```

Comment: It would be good to post your DDL as a sqlfiddle.  Then share your attempts on trying to retrieve the records based on the criteria defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need below query -

```
SELECT D.name, SUM(cost)
FROM sales S
JOIN dep D ON S.dep_id = D.id
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM time) = 2014
AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM time) = 3
GROUP BY D.name
HAVING SUM(cost) < 400
```